# How do I keep a textbox scrolled to the end even after I switch focus to another textbox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textbox, focus

I have two textboxes, textboxB copies from textboxA every time the text is changed but textboxA doesn't keep scrolling to the end.  They're both one line textboxes that must have the cursor at the end 100% of the time.  pls help.

```
    private void Question_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        autoComplete.Text = Question.Text;
        autoComplete.Focus();
        autoComplete.Select(autoComplete.Text.Length, 0);
        Question.Focus();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
TextboxA.CaretIndex = TextboxA.Text.Length;